# pass select value and retrieve data from mysql

Tags: mysql, drop-down-menu, where-clause

I'm working on dynamic pages. The scenario goes like this.

- Page 1 consists of a drop down menu for me to select.
- The selected menu value will pass to the next page URL.
- Then this value will be retrieved by the page to compare and filter the MYSQL Table field name.
- The table consists of 4 main categories which was the option given to the user to select in page 1.
- For each category there will be 30 words stored.
- When the user searches for a certain word, it is supposed to ask for an option by displaying the drop down and checking if this value is the same as the value of field id of the table and the word is now used to narrow down to just search in this field instead of all 4 categories.

How to do this? I was working on this for few weeks but I can't solve it.

```
$ret1 = "SELECT * FROM $db_tb_name WHERE MATCH
 ('categoryid'='.$selectvalueid.') AND AGAINST ('%$str%' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
```

and I have this piece of code and it has wrong syntax.

Please someone help me with some example.

Comment: please rephrase point 5 specially... 30 words stored? where? you may say in table:) but that is not understandable as well.. try to clarify it please

Answer (score 0):

So let me get this straight: at the time you issue your request, you have both a category id `$selectvalueid` (resulting from the drop down) and a search term `$str` (resulting from a free text entry?). And you want those rows where the `categoryid` column of your table *exactly matches* the `$selectvalueid` string from your script, while some other column (with what name?) *contains* the `$str` value. Is that correct so far?

If it is, your query might look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM $db_tb_name
WHERE categoryid = '$selectvalueid'
  AND wordcolumn LIKE '%$str%'
```

Note that simply pasting user input variables into SQL queries most likely will make your site vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. So a better way would be using queries with placeholders, and using prepared statements to fill in those placeholders in a safe way when executing the query. How to do that depends on the application language.

Comment: Hi MvG Thanks for the feedback. After editing this, I don't have any syntax error but no result was shown.